# Can Repeater Model execute JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, xml, qt, qml, repeater

I have an XmlListModel in QML

```
XmlListModel {
 id: model
 source: "qrc:/Config/myConfig.xml"
 query: "/levels/level"
 XmlRole { name: "levName"; query: "@levName/string()" }
 XmlRole { name: "from"; query: "from/number()" }
 XmlRole { name: "to"; query: "to/number()" }
}
```

that reads this XML file

```
<levels parId = "3">
 <level levelName = "level1">
  <from>0</from>
  <to>1</to
 </level>
 <level levelName = "level2">
  <from>1</from>
  <to>2</to>
 </level>
</levels>
```

I also have a text element:

```
Text {
    id: myText
    x: 0; y:0
    text: ""
}
```

I need to iterate through the `XmlListModel` in order to assign to `myText.text` the right level on the basis of what I found in `myList.get(3).value`, where `myList` is a `ListModel`.

Example:
if `myList.get(3).value` is between `0` (included) and `1` (excluded) I have to set `myText.text = "level1"`, if it is between `1` (included) and `2` (excluded) I have to set `myText.text = "level2"`, and so on...

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't really get what's with the `XmlListModel`, the `ListModel` and where your `Repeater` might be... But you can have JavaScript in the binding of the `text`-property, like this: `text: "level " + (Math.floor(myList.get(3).value) + 1)`

Comment: I need the XmlListModel 'cause I don't want to display directly the value of a parameter, but its corresponding level (which I find in the XML file). So the solution you've provided is not working for me..

Comment: what shall be the value of `myText.text`? What things can you ensure about your XML file (like: are the `from` and `to` always `1` appart, and always of type `int`? Are they in the right order? Are they continuous? So can I be sure, that `model.get(n)` gives me the entry for the range from `n` to `n+1`?

Comment: They are of type float in general, and they are defining an interval where the lower limit is included, and the upper excluded. The interval itself is continuous by nature, but the whole sequence of intervals can even build a range with gaps (example given: the first interval goes from 0 to 1 (excluded), the second from 1 (included) to 2, and the last from 5 to 6). But yes, the sequence of intervals is declared in the right order!

Comment: I have to check which numeric value is saved in myList.get(3).value and then to display the correspondent string! E.g. if myList.get(3).value is equal to 0.5 I have to display level1.

Comment: Ok, so: You instantiate the `ListModel` with a `Repeater`. The `ListModel` has a role `value` and you want to look up the corresponding string from your `XmlListModel` to display it in the delegate?

Comment: No, I instantiate the ListModel without a Repeater. The ListModel has a role value and I want to look up the corresponding string from my XmlListModel to display it in a Text element. The Repeater is a possible solution of mine for iterating between xml levels, so I can establish which string to choose. Maybe its wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't query your XmlListModel in `O(1)` like `give me the value, where x is between role from and role to`.

Good for you, you have an ordered list, so you can perform a binary search on your `XmlListModel`. The algorithm basically goes like this:

You first check whether your search value is by coincidence the one in the middle. If it is smaller, you search in the middle of the lower half, if it is larger, you search in the upper half... and so on.
With this you can find your value in `O(log n)` where `n` is the number of entries in your `XmlListModel`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

If you have this implemented, to work on your model - either in JavaScript or in C++ or Python... you can have it like this:

```
Text {
    text: binarySearch(model, myList.get(3).value).levName
}
```

When you implement this algorithm, make sure to deal with the gaps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion :-)))